# How can I get current field value of a changed document in mongoengine?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

When I change document I see field new value. But sometimes I want to see its old value (or it would be correctly say, its current value). I know that I can see changed fields in `_changed_fields` attribute and something tells me that I can see the current value too. But I can't find where. And my searches gave no result.

What I want to notice: I want to find the solution for `mongoengine`, not for `pymongo`. Because I know that I can query document by `pymongo` and get the document, but it is an extra query to database and I would prefer not to bother db once more.

So, repeating the question above: how can I get current field value of a changed document in `mongoengine`?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in question there is a solution with `pymongo`:

```
user = User.objects.with_id(some_id)
user.email = 'test@mail.ru'
# And then somewhere below I want to see an old value
# For example, I want 'email' field
user_coll = User._get_collection()
user_data = user_coll.find_one({'_id': user}, {'_id': 0, 'email': 1})
old_value = user_data.get('email', '')
```

But there was an extra query to database. And because of it I want to find solution with `mongoengine`.